# Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at /usr/share/perl5/Net/Server/Fork.pm line 168

Tags: perl, munin

On my new Debian Bookworm, the file `/usr/share/perl5/Net/Server/Fork.pm` generates an error in logs each time Munin calls it. The error logged is

> "Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==)  at
> /usr/share/perl5/Net/Server/Fork.pm line 168."

In Debian Bullseye, there is no error.

By the way, here are the differences between the two versions :

```
5c5
< #  Copyright (C) 2001-2017
---
> #  Copyright (C) 2001-2022
146a147
>         $self->register_child($pid, 'fork');
167c168
<     if (SOCK_DGRAM == $sock->getsockopt(SOL_SOCKET,SO_TYPE)) {
---
>     if (SOCK_DGRAM == unpack('i', $sock->getsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_TYPE))) {
```

The line 168 is the last diff, where the problem occurs.

I don't know the Perl, so how can I solve this and report the error to Perl package owner ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this issue is already reported to the project in [github perl-net-server issue 32](https://github.com/rhandom/perl-net-server/issues/32).  You could add your own analysis there to see if this can get better attention.

I don't see it reported in the [central Perl bug tracking system](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Net-Server) so you might want to add it there.  If so, please include a link to the github issue.

The code fix for this should be pretty easy:

```
my $sockopt = unpack('i', $sock->getsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_TYPE));
if (defined $sockopt and SOCK_DGRAM == $sockopt) {
```

assuming that variable name isn't used nearby in the code.